# Thom's (parametric) transversality theorem in the complex case

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, transversality

I need a version of the parametric [transversality theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_theorem) for the complex case. The original one is:

> Let $M,\ N,\ Z,\ S$ be smooth manifolds. If a smooth map $F\colon M\times S \rightarrow N\supset Z$ is transversal to $Z,$ then for almost all $s\in S,$ $F_s$ is transversal to $Z.$

I'd like a reference for the version of this statement for complex manifolds and a holomorphic map $F$.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but doesn't the statement for the underlying smooth manifolds of the complex manifolds provide what you need?

Comment: I think so, but I never saw any version of it for the holomorphic maps and complex manifolds. I would like to see a reference just to be sure I'm not missing some important detail.